# Plain Ruby: set only timezone for a DateTime instance

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

All the existing answers either use a lib or Rails. I need to do this in plain Ruby. I also find it hard to imagine that a beautiful language like Ruby would make this so difficult.

I have many date strings of the form: `07 Nov 20`. I am able to parse these into a `DateTime` instance using:

```rb
> require 'time'
=> true
> DateTime.strptime("07 Nov 20", "%d %b %y")
=> #<DateTime: 2020-11-07T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459161j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
> _.new_offset("+05:30")
=> #<DateTime: 2020-11-07T05:30:00+05:30 ((2459161j,0s,0n),+19800s,2299161j)>
```

As we can see, using `DateTime#new_offset` changes not only the offset, but *also change the time*. There doesn't seem to exist any other method to *only* change the timezone and/or offset either.

If possible, I'd also like to do this for that individual `DateTime` instance and not all `DateTime` instances created in the future via some `TIMEZONE` global or something.

**Note**: While the input string doesn't contain any time component, I still need my runtime representation to have one. So while using a simpler method like `Date#strptime` would work, it is not "ideal".

**Note 2**: I'm guessing there are other complications with simply "setting" the timezone, which is why this function is not present. For example it is not obvious how to handle DST when you "set" the timezone. I'm guessing that changing the time is going to be inevitable if you want to ensure that passing in a valid offset will always return a valid `DateTime` instance.

---

**Edit 1**:
Further digging in the source code for date (`date/date_core.c`) reveals the `set_of` function is used to set the offset for a `DateTime` instance. Unfortunately, it seems that the logic of [manipulating the offset is coupled](https://github.com/ruby/date/blob/74df34d5be195d9dcfc49cf39ee0f2315dd3073a/ext/date/date_core.c#L5510) with the manipulation of the time. This explains why there is no method exposed in the Ruby stdlib to only set the offset.

Comment: They're dates, should they have a time or time zone? Should you be using [`Date.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) instead?

Comment: Yea okay. I think that's one way to solve the problem. :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

Should they be `Date` objects instead? Dates don't have times nor time zones.

```
Date.strptime("07 Nov 20", "%d %b %y")
```

Otherwise, you can add a time zone to the string and parse it.

```
string = "07 Nov 20"
p DateTime.strptime("#{string}+0530", "%d %b %y %z")
```

Or you can subtract the extra hours. `DateTime` subtracts number of days and will take a fraction.

```
DateTime.strptime("07 Nov 20", "%d %b %y").new_offset("+05:30") - 5.5/24
```

Comment: @Shwern, I have some other use cases where the strings actually are Date _and_ Time instances. Currently. I am already doing the string concat thing you've mentioned.

Comment: @SatyajeetKanetkar It works. You could also subtract the 5.5 hours after converting the time zone. `dt - 5.5/24`.